# Empty programmatically created form javascript

Tags: javascript

I've created this form:

```
 $('#confirmed-drop').click(function(){
      var form=document.createElement('FORM');
      form.name='drop-form';
      form.method='POST';
      form.action='dar-baja';

      var reason=document.createElement('INPUT');
      reason.type='TEXT';
      reason.name='reason';
      reason.value=$("#motivos_baja option:selected").val();
      form.appendChild(reason);

      document.body.appendChild(form);
      form.submit();
 });
```

but in the destination url `$_POST` is empty, do I missed something?

Comment: Why don't you use `$.post()` or `$.ajax()`?

Comment: And why do you even use jQuery, if nearly your whole code is vanilla js?!

Comment: `form.action='dar-baja';` ... well, that doesn't look like it would be a PHP file ... but you say `$_POST is empty` - which does suggest PHP ... have you tried adding `.php` to the action and the file on the server

Comment: 'dar-baja' its a codeigniter url